# Trying to restore a database from a large .sql file using sqlcmd - error

Tags: database, restore, sqlcmd

I am trying to **restore database** data using the following command from a large `.sql` file

```
Type myfile.sql | sqlsmd –S server –U username –P password
```

I get the following error:

```
Sqlcmd: Error: Scripting error.
```

I am unable to open the file, there is not enough memory.

Answer (score 2):

SQLCMD has a "-i" inputfile parameter as well - I'd recommend using that. "Type"-ing the file and piping your output into SQLCMD is a hackish way to run the file, especially when the command line includes native support for reading from a file. Try this:

```
sqlcmd –S server –U username –P password -i MyFile.sql
```

Answer (score 1):

you could try using [isql](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214012(SQL.80).aspx) which has a -i input file option - that loses the nasty

```
Type myfile.sql |
```

You don't say which version of Sql you're using, but you could probably run your file in using DTS/SSIS, if you go with that approach you'll be able to turn on logging and actually see which line(s) fail, and set a threshold for an acceptable number of failing lines.

Another way is to use management studio to open the file and then execute it.

Comment: can u help me on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7080893/having-problems-trying-to-restore-encrypted-database) please

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
@echo Server:   %1
@echo Database: %2
@echo User: %3
@echo Password:   %4


set ISQLCMD=SQLCMD -S %1 -d %2 -U %3 -P %4 -m1 -i
```