# having problems trying to restore encrypted database

Tags: database, sql-server-2008, restore, database-restore, encryption

Im trying to copy an encrypted database from the default server to my server for testing purposes

but im having troubles doing so because i have never done it
so im going to explain my procedure and the errors i got

first i create a master key :

```
USE master
GO
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='DB-PaSSw0rD'
GO
```

all is good for now :
**Command(s) completed successfully.**

then i create a certificate by importing the certificate  created on the default server:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE TDECERT
FROM FILE = 'C:\temp\TDECert.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'C:\temp\TDECertKey.pvk' , 
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='pAssW0rD')
GO
```

but i get :
**Msg 15581, Level 16, State 1, Line 1**

**Please create a master key in the database or open the master key in the session before performing this operation.**

to resolve this i try to open the master key:

```
OPEN MASTER KEY DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='DB-PaSSw0rD'
ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY
```

but i get : 
**Cannot find the symmetric key 'master key', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

then to resolve this second issue i try to grant it access:

```
GRANT CONTROL ON CERTIFICATE :: TDECERT To Administrator
```

but i get :
**Cannot find the certificate 'TDECERT', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.**

thanks in advance for ur time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

problem solved

all i had to do is add

> USE master

before

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE TDECERT
FROM FILE = 'C:\temp\TDECert.cer'
WITH PRIVATE KEY (FILE = 'C:\temp\TDECertKey.pvk' , 
DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='pAssW0rD')
GO
```

and didnt need anything else

that easy!